# How do I export this MongoDB data into a CSV file (a "join" of two collections)?

Tags: mongodb, csv

I have a database with two collections.

Collection `cars` has documents that look like this:

```
{ license_number: "123456", name: "tesla" }
{ license_number: "654321", name: "ford" }
{ license_number: "987654", name: "volvo" }
```

Collection `greatCars` has documents that look like this:

```
{ license_number: "123456" }
```

I want to export a "join" of these two collections into a CSV file that looks like this:

```
license_number, name,  isGreat
123456,         tesla, TRUE
654321,         ford,  FALSE
987654,         volvo, FALSE
```

(Please don't take offense. It's just an example and I know nothing about cars.)

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974925/how-can-i-work-with-join-to-export-data-from-mongodb)

Comment: @khakishoiab thanks, put this in an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: for your convinience I have put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a short javascript program that will transfer the data you want to export into a new temporary collection, that can be exported.

create a file  `export.js:`

> ```
>  //initialise the export results collection   
>      db.export.results.drop()`;   
>      //create a cursor containing the contents of the list1 collection  
>      cursor = db.list1.find();
>         while (cursor.hasNext()) {
>             doc = cursor.next();
>          //Check if the document exists in the list2 collection
>          list2 = db.list2.find({"<id_fieldname>": doc.<id_fieldname>});
>          if (list2.hasNext()) {
>              //if it does exist, add the document from list1 to the new export collection
>             db.export.results.insert(doc);
>          }
>      }
>      print(db.export.results.count() + " matching documents found");
> ```

Run this from the cmd line:

```
# mongo "localhost:27017/<dbname>" export.js
```

It will create a collection called `export.results` containing the document from the list1 collection with documents in the list2 (in your case `cars` and `greatCars`)collection with a matching id field. You can then export or dump this collection:

```
# mongoexport --db <dbname> -c export.results -type csv -o <file_name>
```